# Unpredictable output of simple C Program

Tags: c, turbo-c

I am practicing c programming from the very beginning, but when I execute simple C program to add two numbers, I got unexpected output, I am not able to figure it out, can anyone provide the detailed explanation of how the compiler works behind the scene for this output.

Here is the mentioned code. I am using basic turbo IDE

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int a,b,c=0;
clrscr();
printf("Enter two numbers:");
scanf("%d%d", &a,&b);
c=a+b;
printf("sum of two numbers are %d", &c);
getch();
}


Output:

Enter two numbers:1
2
sum of two numbers are -16
```

Comment: Do you know what `&c` means?

Comment: `&c` is just like `&a` and `&b` :)

Comment: address of operator prefix variable name c

Comment: @Jack So why are you printing its address?

Comment: ohhh thats the trick :)

Comment: *turbo-c* are you sure? If you are not running on a toaster, you're better off getting a real compiler.

Comment: Probably: MSVC has a `conio` library but no `clrscr()` function. There is also the turbo-C tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in line :-

```
printf("sum of two numbers are %d", &c);`
```

Change  it to :-

```
printf("sum of two numbers are %d", c);
```

`&c` is used when you want to print address.

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a, b, c = 0;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter two numbers:");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    c = a + b;
    printf("sum of two numbers are %d", c); // not &c
    getch();
}
```

Output :-

```
Enter two numbers:3                                                                                                                                                                    
5                                                                                                                                                                                      
sum of two numbers are 8
```

Turbo c is very outdated.Try `gcc` *(IDEs like CodeBlocks)* . Also make sure that your code is **intended** properly.

Comment: Thank you so much all of you, its a very very silly mistake and you guys save my lot of time..:)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you used the address-of operator on the variable `c` where you did not need to. `&c` is a *pointer* to `c`, so when you print it out you are actually trying to print the memory address of `c` rather than the integer value stored there, leading to unexpected output. So

```
printf("sum of two numbers are %d", &c);
```

should become

```
printf("sum of two numbers are %d", c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are typing the wrong syntax of `printf`
use this:
`printf("sum of two numbers are %d",c);`